# A relatively compact collection of linear functionals in the comapct open topology and convergence in the operator norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a real separable Hilbert space and $\{ v_n : H \to \mathbb{R} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a collection of continuous linear functions on $H$.

Suppose that

1. $\{ v_n \}$ is relatively compact in the dual space $H'$ with respect to
   the "compact open topology", that is the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $H$.
2. $\{ v_n \}$ is bounded with respect to the "uniform topology"(=operator norm topology) $H'$.

Now, I have two questions that really confuse me.

1. Let us fix an orthonormal basis $\{ e_j \}_{j=1}^\infty$ of $H$ and denote by $H_N$ the span of $\{ e_1, \cdots, e_N\}$ for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, since $H_N$ is finite dimensional, the unit sphere $\{ v \in H_N \mid \lVert v \rVert_H=1\}$ is compact in $H$. Let us denote by $\lVert v_n \lVert_{N,op}$ the operator norm of the restricted map $v_n \mid_{H_N} : H_N \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, does relative compactness imply that
   \begin{equation}
   \lVert v_n - v_{n'} \rVert_{N,op} \to 0 \text{ as } n,n' \to \infty
   \end{equation}
   for each fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$?
2. By construction, I see that $\lVert v_n \lVert_{N,op} \to \lVert v_n \lVert_{op}$ as $N \to \infty$, where $\lVert v_n \lVert_{op}$ is the operator norm of $v_n$ on whole $H$. However, I don't think the compact-open topology on $H'$ is in general equal to the uniform topology on $H$.

Nevertheless, can we do something with the boundedness of $\{v_n \}$ with respect to $\lVert \cdot \lVert_{op}$? For example, can we conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lVert v_n - v_{n'} \rVert_{op} \to 0 \text{ as } n,n' \to \infty
\end{equation}
as well?

These two questions really bother me....Could anyone please help?

Comment: Even for $H=\mathbb R$, you can only get the convergence of a **subsequence** given only the relatively compactness and the boundedness (which in this case is equivalent to the relatively compactness).